# YARN - Need to run a job before killing another job

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

In our application we have a main Spark job[Job 1]. Whenever the main Spark job is killed for any reason, we need to submit another Spark job[Job 2].

Is it possible to submit a Spark job[Job 2] whenever YARN tries to kill the main Spark job[Job 1]?

Comment: Are you using any workflow manager

Comment: How you are submitting/scheduling the jobs. Share that information.

Comment: @Amit Kumar : We submit spark job using spark-submit command as usual : **spark-submit  --class className --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --supervise  --executor-memory 2G --driver-memory 2G jarName.jar**

Comment: @Achyuth Reg **Workflow manager** : We have Zookeeper installed. Bu we are not using Zookeeper to manage Spark Applications

Answer (score 0):

Option1: If you are not using any scheduling engine, then the option is to use SparkLauncher to trigger your spark jobs programmability. From a normal scala application, you can trigger the first spark job using Spark launcher, and poll for its final status. based on the final status "Failed/killed", launch the 2nd job.
A pseudo code is as below :

```
import org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher

object SparkSchedule {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    //launch job1
    val job1 = new SparkLauncher()
      .setAppResource("/usr/local/spark/lib/spark-examples-1.6.3-hadoop2.6.0.jar")
      .setMainClass("org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi")
      .setMaster("local")
      .setAppName("launch")
      .setVerbose(true).startApplication()

    println("app id" + job1.getAppId)
    println("app state" + job1.getState)

    while (!(job1.getState.isFinal())) {
      //waiting for the job1 completion status
      println("app is final" + job1.getState.isFinal())
      Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
    val finalJobState = job1.getState;//get the final status of the job1
    //check for failed or killed and launch job2
    if(finalJobState.equalsIgnoreCase("Failed") || finalJobState.equalsIgnoreCase("killed")){
      //launch the job2 same way as above 
      val job2 = new SparkLauncher()
      .setAppResource("/usr/local/spark/lib/spark-examples-1.6.3-hadoop2.6.0.jar")
      .setMainClass("org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi")
      .setMaster("local")
      .setAppName("launch")
      .setVerbose(true).startApplication()
    }
  }
}
```

You can run the "SparkSchedule" class either through scala jar option, or you can submit it through spark submit as well(if you this make sure the jars path you specified in setAppResource are available for the spark driver).

Option 2: Use oozie to schedule you job. Use oozie spark action to run job 1. Oozie provides two tags: `<ok to="finish"> and <error to="job2">`. In case of error it will go the spark action for job2.

Answer (score 0):

In your case yo have to grep the yarn application id from the spark-submit and check the status of the job

```
yarn application -status {Application ID}
```

Yo need a loop in a shell script and start when it completes the process.

**oozie is a solution for job dependency.**

```
<action name='l1persistence'>
        <spark
            xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <master>${master}</master>
            <name>process</name>
            <class>Driverpath</class>
            <jar>${appLib}</jar>
            <spark-opts>--jars ${sparkLib} --files ${hiveSite}</spark-opts>
            <arg>${resourcePath}/${layer1PropertiesFileName}</arg>
            <arg>${resourcePath}/${envConfigPropertiesFileName}</arg>
            <arg>PersistenceLayer1</arg>
            <arg>${resourcePath}/${dqPropertiesFileName}</arg>
        </spark>
        <ok to='nextjob' />
        <error to="sendEmailKill" />
    </action>
```

Answer (score -2):

It should be ok, because when job 1 dies, it doesn't affect the operation of job 2